# issue building R package from tar ball

Tags: r

I would love to build a package from this tar ball:

```
[https://github.com/suiji/Arborist/commit/b8b9f463eb474bcb118752a5f25cfd410ffc56e5][1]
```

I struggled with it and get:

```
installing source package 'Rborist' ...
** libs
*** arch - i386
Error in .shlib_internal(args) :
C++14 standard requested but CXX14 is not defined
```

I used:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("suiji/Rborist")
```

and

```
library(githubinstall)
githubinstall("suiji/Rborist")
```

Could someone please help me? Even build the package for windows 7? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you compiler does not support C++14, so the compiler should be updated. If you run on windows, I do not know how to do it but it is a starting point for you to google it

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56328910

Comment: Thanks. I googled this of course. In fact, I tried the suggested if I remember correctly. Will try again.